# Collect pattern (Log's)

Tags: pattern-matching

Is it possible to apply "Collect" command  (to put Log's in particular combination) to factor out (pattern) a particular form from the full expression.

For example, consider the following expression:

```
Log[a] + Log[b] - Log[c] + Log[d] - Log[f]
```

And I need to get a

```
Log[ab/c] - Log[f/d]
```

How one can do it??

Thanks in advance!!

A.

**EDIT**

My concrete example is:

Given this expression:

```
-(1/2) Log[(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\))] (Log[(
    Subscript[t, 1] Subscript[t, 3])/(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\) μ^2)] - 1/ϵ)
```

and applying ExpanAll[PowerExpand[%]] leads to

```
Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)]/(2 ϵ) + 
 Log[μ] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] + Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)]/(2 ϵ) + 
 Log[μ] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] + 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] + 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)]^2 - Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)]/(2 ϵ) - 
 Log[μ] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] - 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] - Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)]/(2 ϵ) - 
 Log[μ] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] - 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] - 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] - 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] + 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] + 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] - 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]] - 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]] + 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]] + 
 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]]
```

How to get from the last expression (a very long) the first (combined) one?

I know, that I need to factor out this factor

```
Log[(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\))]
```

Naively:

```
Collect[expression, Log[(
    \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\) 
    \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
    \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\) 
    \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\))] ]
```

Comment: Will this work? `Log[a] + Log[b] - Log[c] + Log[d] - 
  Log[f] //. {Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[x y], 
  Log[x_] - Log[y_] -> Log[x/y]}`

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: For me it says that the big expression in the edit section is incomplete. It is not formatted in such a way that I will enjoy going through it..

Comment: I have gone through it and there is a comma in the third line from the bottom that doesn't belong there.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom, sorry for the typo. I've corrected it.
If you copy-paste into Math. notebook it should work properly (I checked).

Comment: @AndrewKor It's always good to check if things work, especially in questions and especially with hard to read code. But I admit that it is hard to make things look nice here as long as you use sub/superscripts. So: No problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do it with `Collect`, but one thing you could do is to express, say, $s_{\{1,2\}}$ in terms of the factor you want to pull out, and use replacement rules to transform the expression.

I've altered the notation here as subscripts and Greek letters are hard to read in `InputForm`.

Starting with your expanded expression

```
expr = Log[s12]/(2 e) + Log[m] Log[s12] - Log[s345]/(2 e) - 
 Log[m] Log[s345] + Log[s45]/(2 e) + Log[m] Log[s45] + 
 1/2 Log[s12] Log[s45] - 1/2 Log[s345] Log[s45] + Log[s45]^2/2 - 
 Log[s456]/(2 e) - Log[m] Log[s456] - 1/2 Log[s45] Log[s456] - 
 1/2 Log[s12] Log[t1] + 1/2 Log[s345] Log[t1] - 
 1/2 Log[s45] Log[t1] + 1/2 Log[s456] Log[t1] - 
 1/2 Log[s12] Log[t3] + 1/2 Log[s345] Log[t3] - 
 1/2 Log[s45] Log[t3] + 1/2 Log[s456] Log[t3]
```

Express `s12` in terms of the factor you want to extract (represented here by the symbol `factor`)

```
Simplify @ PowerExpand[expr /. s12 -> Exp[factor] s345 s456/s45]
```

> ```
> (factor (1 + 2 e Log[m] + e Log[s45] - e Log[t1] - e Log[t3]))/(2 e)
> ```

Then just replace `factor` with the actual expression

```
% /. factor -> Log[(s12 s45)/(s345 s456)]
```

> ```
> (Log[(s12 s45)/(s345 s456)] *
>    (1 + 2 e Log[m] + e Log[s45] - e Log[t1] - e Log[t3]))/(2 e)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be as follows. Here is your expression:

```
 expr1 = Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)]/(2 \[Epsilon]) +  
   Log[\[Mu]] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] + Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)]/(2 \[Epsilon]) +  
   Log[\[Mu]] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] + 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] + 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)]^2 - Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)]/(2 \[Epsilon]) -  
   Log[\[Mu]] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] - 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] - Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)]/(2 \[Epsilon]) -  
   Log[\[Mu]] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] - 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] - 1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] -  
   1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] +
    1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] +  
   1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 1]] -  
   1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]] -  
   1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]] +  
   1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]] + 
   1/2 Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\)] Log[Subscript[t, 3]];
```

Let us simplify it assuming that some of your variables are positive:

```
    expr2 = Simplify[expr1, {
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\) > 0, 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\) > 0, 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\) > 0, 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\) > 0}]

(*  The result: 
(Log[(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 6}\)]\))] (1 + 
   2 \[Epsilon] Log[\[Mu]] + \[Epsilon] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] - \[Epsilon] Log[Subscript[t,
      1]] - \[Epsilon] Log[Subscript[t, 3]]))/(2 \[Epsilon])           *)
```

Now let us take the subexpression that had not beed transformed yet:

```
expr2[[4]]


(*  1 + 2 \[Epsilon] Log[\[Mu]] + \[Epsilon] Log[
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\)] - \[Epsilon] Log[Subscript[t,
    1]] - \[Epsilon] Log[Subscript[t, 3]]
*)
```

Let us call the Rest of it subExp1 and transform it separately:

```
subExp1 = 
 Simplify[Simplify[
    expr2[[4]] // Rest, {Subscript[t, 1] > 0, 
     Subscript[t, 3] > 0, \[Mu] > 0, 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\) > 0, \[Epsilon] > 0}] /. 
   Times[2, Log[x_]] -> Log[x^2], \[Mu] > 0] 

(* \[Epsilon] Log[(\[Mu]^2 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
  Subscript[t, 1] Subscript[t, 3])] *)
```

Now let us collect them together:

```
ReplacePart[expr1, {4} -> 1 + subExp1]
```

The result is below:

```
(Log[(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({1, 2}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({3, 4, 5}\)]\) 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5, 
     6}\)]\))] (1 + \[Epsilon] Log[(\[Mu]^2 
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(s\), \({4, 5}\)]\))/(
     Subscript[t, 1] Subscript[t, 3])]))/(2 \[Epsilon])
```